# jQuery with slideshow in Ruby On Rails

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make a slideshow with jQuery. **I have the photos in an array** but I don't know how to create the slideshow. I've taken a look at 'http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/' but I have no idea what to do.

and in views>layouts>application

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#shuffle').cycle({ 
    fx:     'shuffle', 
    delay:  -4000 
});
});
```

**to view the photos I have this (but this shows me all the photos at once):**

```
    <div id="shuffle">
    <% @building.building_photos.each do |photo| %>
      <%= link_to (image_tag (photo.photo.url)), @building %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
```

UPDATE 1(source code)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Welcome to koshbay</title>
  <link href="/assets/all.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/about.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/addphotos.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/admin.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/buildings.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/contact.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/forrent.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/forsale.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/projectproperties.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/rended.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/rented.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/seeits.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sessions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/sold.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/soon.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/store.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery-ui.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jrails.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.2.72.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#shuffle').cycle({ 
    fx:     'shuffle', 
    easing: 'easeOutBack', 
    delay:  -4000 
});
});



</script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="hCMHawSL0iZidEaHMt8D7T1YhYAuwpzXCdvtwyHxiC0=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body id="store" >
    <div id="banner" >
     <img alt="Welcome" src="/assets/welcome.jpg" />
     Welcome to KTIMABAY

     </div>

     <div id="side" >     

     <a href="/">Home</a>   <br/>
     <a href="http://www..../faq" >Questions</a><br />
     <a href="/about/index">About</a><br/>
      <a href="/contact/index">Contact</a>  <br/>   

      <a href="/sessions/new">Login</a> <br/>
     <br />


     </div>
     <div id="main" >
     <p id="notice"></p>

<p>
 <div id="shuffle">
      <a href="/buildings/27"><img alt="House-exterior-design-wallpaper-actrists-bollywood" src="/system/building_photos/photos/000/000/017/original/House-exterior-design-wallpaper-actrists-bollywood.jpg?1363274173" /></a>
      <a href="/buildings/27"><img alt="House-interior-design-8" src="/system/building_photos/photos/000/000/018/original/House-Interior-Design-8.jpg?1363274173" /></a>
      <a href="/buildings/27"><img alt="Jesse-james-home-bad-feng-shui-bedroom" src="/system/building_photos/photos/000/000/019/original/jesse-james-home-bad-feng-shui-bedroom.jpg?1363274173" /></a>

  </div>
<p>
  <b>Title:</b>
  lefkeri
</p>

<p>
  <b>Status:</b>
  For Rent
</p>

<p>
  <b>Description:</b>
  2 bedrooms
</p>

<p>
  <b>Price:</b>
   € 500.0
</p>

<form action="/seeits/27?building_id=27" class="button_to" method="post"><div><input type="submit" value="I want to see it" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="hCMHawSL0iZidEaHMt8D7T1YhYAuwpzXCdvtwyHxiC0=" /></div></form>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Any ideas as to how I could do this (first time I have to use jQuery and for this reason I don't know how to do it)?

Comment: if you look at the source code on cycle by malsup, you see its just a div id named slideshow wrapped around a bunch of img tags, in your javascript you would simply attach cycle to it like so `$('#slideshow').cycle();` thats a basic way it works. so you want to show all of the photos at once

Comment: i update my question.i have done those but nothing has changed.

Comment: can you post the html source, so i can see whats its printing

Comment: i posted it.have a look plz

Comment: i dont see the cycle plugin js file in your script tags below the jquery lib file

Comment: now i have include it?(i update the source code in answer)

Comment: you didnt close your document ready with `});` also make sure you have easing plugin hooked up as well

Comment: you are right when i put }); it shows me only one image put not changing the photo. i havent install the easing plugin.is this why not changing the photo? must install it? and how? thanks

Comment: remove `easing: 'easeOutBack'` and see if that helps otherwise add easing which can be found [**here**](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: WOW!!! IT WORKS!!! if you want write answer to accept it! THANKS

Comment: there's your answer below: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add the missing `});` for your closing `document ready`

Next either remove `easing: 'easeOutBack'` inside your cycle plugin call

or add the easing library from this link found [**here**](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: i have correct it and now the question is just like you say and works.THANKS